# What would be required to allow for single sign on in a python web application?

Tags: python, active-directory, single-sign-on, wsgi

I would like to know how to implement single sign on in a python web application. The application would run on a Windows Server in an Active Directory domain.

The clients would also be in the domain.

What I would like is that the authentication occurs automatically, like Windows Authentication in Asp.Net (The browser automatically authenticates the user using NTLM or whatever, without ever popping a credentials window).

Is there a library that supports handling the authentication against Active directory or better yet, that generates all the required http headers ?

The application would probably be developped using flask or bottle.

It would also be cool if there as a wsgi middleware that does this authentication automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Try [sso.py](http://liftoff.github.io/GateOne/Developer/sso.html). I haven't tried it myself, but it looks promising.

Comment: It seems interesting, thanks, I will take a look. However, this seems to be Tornado specific, which is a bit sad, but it is still better than nothing.